# javascript: shortcut build-in object function (setInterval)

Tags: javascript

I was doing something similar to this few days ago and it worked perfectly , now i try to write it same as it was and it's not working , somehow.

what's the problem here?

```
var win = window ,
    setInter = "setInterval";       
win[setInter](function(){alert();}, 1000);
```

as i mention before , it was written 2 days ago and it work perfectly , now i tried to rewrite it and somehow it not working , am i missing here something?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you `alert()` without a parameter?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UubPY/

Comment: @hair: Yes, it will pop up "undefined" (the "value" of parameters that weren't passed to a function) in that case. (On My Browser™)

Comment: oh snap , this is the dumbest question ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you supply nothing to the `alert()` method it will open no window. Just add a String like `alert('test');`

Comment: Works fine for me without an argument. What browser(s) failed for you?

Comment: I remember this being fickle in some browsers. Maybe some FF versions that didn't work with an empty alert IIRC?

Comment: Firefox does not, and I remember IE (at least 7) doesn't either. I think this behavior is intended, since displaying empty messages will only annoy the user without any other effect.

Comment: At least in the latest Firefox 7, it throws an error: `Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindowInternal.alert]`. And there's no alert window. http://jsfiddle.net/E8LSg/

Answer (score 0):

It does work, at least in chrome, I changed it to setTimeout so it doesn't annoy people

http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/Tq5S3/1/